# Django with MongoDB and React-native

Tags: django, mongodb, react-native

So I am relatively new and I am looking for a good stack to work on. I want to use react-native on the front-end, Django and MongoDB on the backend. I know I can easily use Node.js as the server but I don't want to.
How good is this combination? Are there any boiler plates available for this? Please suggest.

Comment: Really depends on many parameters you did not describe such as skills, size of app etc. for mobile data storage there is an issue of persistence while working offline , take a look at : https://realm.io/

Comment: So I have worked on MEAN stack so I know Mongo, Node and Javascript. I am learning python. I have beginner level knowledge.  The app is , pretty simple. Standard login, 2 forms on the backend and an web based admin interface for realtime updates and reports. But I am looking for a stack that I can use in the future as well

Comment: You want a good stack to work on and you talk about React-native? I'd strongly suggest to separate everything first. Try a custom Django project on one side, and React-native for another project. Once you get them working and you understand those technologies, try to make project that "mix" them. I would strongly advice not to try them alltogether if you're new to Django.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try that. Does Django work well with Mongo db?

Comment: Djongo works quite well with mongodb. You need a connector like [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) to connect Django and mongodb together.